# Move all folders except one

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two directories dir1 and dir2. I need to move the content of folder dir1 to  dir2 except one folder dir1/src.

I tried this

```
mv !(src) dir1/* dir2/
```

But it dosn't work, it still displays this error

```
bash: !: event not found
```

Comment: Can try i.e.: `find dir1/ -not -name "src" -exec mv "{}" dir2/ \;` to `find` all files in dir1/ except for files with "src" in the name then use `find`'s built-in `exec` to move (`mv`) the files to dir2/

Comment: Try this:-    shell>     mv $(ls dir1/* | grep -v src )  dir2/

Comment: @PrabhatKumar you should **never** actually use unprocessed output from ls - there are too many dangerous scenarios.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329230)?

The answer to my question there states that what you are trying to to is achievable by using the `extglob` bash shell option. You can turn it on by executing `shopt -s extglob` or by adding that command to your `~/.bashrc` and relogin. Afterwards you can use the function.

---

To use your example of moving everything from `dir1` except `dir1/src` to `dir2`, this should work:

```
mv -vt dir2/ dir1/!(src)
```

Example output:

```
$ mkdir -pv dir1/{a,b,c,src} dir2
mkdir: created directory 'dir1'
mkdir: created directory 'dir1/a'
mkdir: created directory 'dir1/b'
mkdir: created directory 'dir1/c'
mkdir: created directory 'dir1/src'
mkdir: created directory 'dir2'
$ ls -l dir1/
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 dw dw 4096 Apr  7 13:30 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 dw dw 4096 Apr  7 13:30 b
drwxrwxr-x 2 dw dw 4096 Apr  7 13:30 c
drwxrwxr-x 2 dw dw 4096 Apr  7 13:30 src
$ ls -l dir2/
total 0
$ shopt -s extglob
$ mv -vt dir2/ dir1/!(src)
'dir1/a' -> 'dir2/a'
'dir1/b' -> 'dir2/b'
'dir1/c' -> 'dir2/c'
$ ls -l dir1/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 dw dw 4096 Apr  7 13:30 src
$ ls -l dir2/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 dw dw 4096 Apr  7 13:30 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 dw dw 4096 Apr  7 13:30 b
drwxrwxr-x 2 dw dw 4096 Apr  7 13:30 c
```

---

More information about extglob can be found [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing).

Comment: Thanks David, I tried your command but I have already this error **bash: !: event not found**

Comment: Did you enable **extglob** by executing `shopt -s extglob` first? The command works just fine for me - I updated my answer with example output.

Comment: But this solution is valid only if the destination directory is empty. for example if there is another folder **dir2/a/file.txt** this solution will not work. I get this error **mv: cannot move « dir1/a » to « dir2/a »: directory is not empty « dir1/b » -> « dir2/b »
« dir1/c » -> « dir2/c »**

Comment: Yes, of course. That's the nature of `mv`. What else did you expect?

Comment: What I need is to replace files or directories if exists. this work for me **cp -fR dir1/* dir2/**